# Move WebAPI hosted in Azure WebSite to Azure API App in Visual Studio 2015 RC

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-apps, azure-app-service-envrmnt

Is it possible to create an Azure API App - or to be more specific - move an existing ASP.NET MVC WebAPI to API Apps, using Visual Studio 2015 RC? I downloaded latest Azure SDK but don't see any Azure App Services functionality in VS 2015 RC. How to enable it? Or isn't it yet available in 2015?

Answer (score 0):

It's not available on the RC version of VS 2015 at this moment. The SDK only targets VS 2013.

We will definitely support VS 2015 though.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed the latest Azure SDK for VS2015RC and it is true that it still does not support Azure API App.

[image: VS2015RC ASP.NET Web App Project templates]

Doing the same above for VS2013, it support to create new Azure API App.
[image: VS2013 ASP.NET Web App Project templates]

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 RTM has the API App Preview template built in if you enable Web developer tools. WTE (Web Tools Extensions) is part of the 2015 build by default.

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't answer the migration issue, Alexander Zeitler has a blog post explaining how to create an API App in Visual Studio 2015 RC.

https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/Deploying-a-ASP-NET-MVC-6-API-as-Azure-API-App-in-Azure-App-Services/

In addition, I'm a Content Developer for Azure App Service (which includes API Apps) and we are in the process of writing a formal topic for using Visual Studio 2015 RC to create API Apps.

That topic should be ready "shortly" although no definite date just yet.

**EDIT:** As the blog post specifically calls out MVC 6, I should make clear that you don’t need MVC 6 as long as you follow these guidelines:

Add Swashbuckle from NuGet

Create apiapp.json file in your project's root with the necessary metadata

Have a Metadata folder with the required json files

Publish to your Azure subscription

Restart the gateway

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert an existing Web API project to work with API Apps, there's a gesture in Visual Studio that enables this. It's also documented on the [Azure.com API Apps area](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-dotnet-create-api-app-visual-studio/). Below is a screen shot of the gesture in Visual Studio.

[image: Enabling a Web API with the API App SDK]

Comment: Is this for ASP.NET 5? Becaue I don't see such options on an ASP.NET 5 project